# reg instantiate with 1 in verilog

Tags: verilog, led

I'm making a simple project with leds blinking every second. Led 1 and 3 blink alternating to led 2 and 4. I've written the following Verilog code:

```
    module leds_blinking(input i_Clk,
output o_LED_1,
output o_LED_2,
output o_LED_3,
output o_LED_4);

parameter c_CYCLESINSECOND = 50_000_000;

reg r_LED_1 = 1;
reg r_LED_2 = 0;
reg r_LED_3 = 1;
reg r_LED_4 = 0;
reg [32:0] r_Count = 0;

always @(posedge i_Clk)
begin
    if (r_Count < c_CYCLESINSECOND)
        r_Count <= r_Count + 1;
    else if (r_Count == c_CYCLESINSECOND)
    begin
        r_LED_1 <= ~r_LED_1;
        r_LED_2 <= ~r_LED_2;
        r_LED_3 <= ~r_LED_3;
        r_LED_4 <= ~r_LED_4;
        r_Count <= 0;
    end
    else 
        r_Count <= 0;
end

assign o_LED_1 = r_LED_1;
assign o_LED_2 = r_LED_2;
assign o_LED_3 = r_LED_3;
assign o_LED_4 = r_LED_4;

endmodule
```

All LEDs are active at the same time, though I instantiated 1,3 other than 2,4.

Comment: Are you ensure in `r_LED_N <= ~r_LED_N;`?  May be it should be  `r_LED_N <= !r_LED_N;`

Comment: This gives the same result as before

Comment: Have you tried to simulate? You should have. Place your testbench in the question. If you synthesize, pay attention that initialization such as `reg r_LED_1 = 1` might not work. Check warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming you are synthesizing and not running simulation on the RTL first. Synthesizer that target for ASIC typically ignore default values and `initial` blocks. Synthesizer that target for FPGA often do. Not knowing which synthesizer you are using it is hard to guess your root causes issue.

However, you can simplify your code and solve your problem by using one registers instead of four. Notice how the `o_LED_#` are driven.

```
always @(posedge i_Clk)
begin
  if (r_Count < c_CYCLESINSECOND)
    r_Count <= r_Count + 1;
  else
  begin
    r_LED <= ~r_LED;
    r_Count <= 0;
  end
end

assign o_LED_1 = r_LED;
assign o_LED_2 = ~r_LED;
assign o_LED_3 = r_LED;
assign o_LED_4 = ~r_LED;
```